# Component wise convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

Attempt:

Comparing real and imaginary parts we get:

$r_n \cos \theta_n \to r \cos \theta$

$r_n \sin \theta_n \to r \sin \theta$ $\,\,$ Thus, we get:

$r_n \cos \theta_n \, . \,r_n \cos \theta_n \to r \cos \theta \, . \, r \cos \theta$

$r_n \sin \theta_n \, . \,r_n \sin \theta_n \to r \sin \theta \, . \, r \sin \theta$

$\implies r_n^2 \sin^2 \theta_n \, + \,r_n^2 \cos^2 \theta_n \to r^2 \sin^2 \theta \,+ \, r^2\cos^2 \theta$

$\implies r_n^2  \to r^2$

How do I conclude from here that $r_n \to r$? Should I approach this differently?

Edit: I just realized I could just compose with square root function.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{{r_n}^2}= \sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} {r_n}^2} = \sqrt{r^2}=r$

Comment: What does this mean ? $\quad \{z: z\le0\}$

Comment: @311411 That's author's abuse of notation. $ \{ z : z \leq 0\} $ means all non-positive real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, given $r_n^2 \to r^2$ and $r_n, r \geq 0$ you can conclude immediately that $r_n \to r$; this follows because the square root function is continuous and thus $r_n = \sqrt{r_n^2} \to \sqrt{r^2} = r$ automatically.

Given this it then follows that $\cos \theta_n \to \cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta_n \to \sin \theta$, so we get $\theta_n \to \theta$, as desired.

**Edit from comments**: Let me spell out this last part.

First, how do we obtain  $\cos \theta_n \to \cos \theta$ (and likewise for $\sin$)? The argument goes that since $r \not = 0$ and $r_n \to r$ there must exist some $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$ we have that $r_n \not = 0$. This then allows us to perform the division by $r_n$ (for $n$ sufficiently large) and obtain $\frac{r_n \cos \theta_n}{r_n} \to \frac{r \cos \theta}{r}$.

Once we have $\cos \theta_n \to \cos \theta$, we can compose with the continuous inverse function $\cos^{-1}$ to obtain $\cos^{-1} \cos \theta_n \to \cos^{-1} \cos \theta$. The problem now is just that we do not know the sign of e.g. $\cos^{-1} \cos \theta_n$ (it could be $\theta_n$ or $-\theta_n$). But we can at least conclude that
$$
\lvert \theta_n \rvert = \lvert \cos^{-1} \cos \theta_n \rvert \to \lvert \cos^{-1} \cos \theta \rvert = \lvert \theta \rvert.
$$

If $\theta = 0$ then we are done, since $\lvert \theta_n \rvert \to 0$ if and only if $\theta_n \to 0$. Otherwise we can assume $\theta \not = 0$, and need to argue that the sign of $\theta_n$ is eventually always the same as the sign of $\theta$ (i.e. for $n$ large enough). We do this just using the fact that $\sin \theta_n \to \sin \theta$; we can assume that $\theta_n \not = 0$ as well (by the same argument I gave above for $r_n$), in which case
$$
\operatorname{sign}(\theta_n) = \operatorname{sign}(\sin \theta_n) \to \operatorname{sign}(\sin \theta) = \operatorname{sign}(\theta).
$$
But now we can just multiply this pair of converging sequences and get:
$$
\theta_n = \operatorname{sign}(\theta_n) \lvert \theta_n \rvert \to \operatorname{sign}(\theta) \lvert \theta \rvert = \theta.
$$ (Here $\operatorname{sign}$ is the so-called "sign-function", which is $1$ on positive reals and $-1$ on negative reals.)

Comment: How do you conclude $ \cos \theta_n \to \cos \theta$? Are you using $r_n$ , $r$ are non-zero and then $\frac{r_n \cos \theta_n}{r_n} \to\frac{r\cos \theta}{r} $?

Comment: @approximation Yes, that's right. We just need that $r \not = 0$ (as in the question statement).

Comment: We are cancelling $r_n$ too though, so we need terms in the sequence to be non-zero too right? But since $z_n= r_n \exp{i \theta_n}$ is a sequence in G and G does not contain the origin, we are guaranteed $r_n$ is non-zero.

Comment: @approximation Yes I am sorry I did not spell this out further. The argument goes that since $r \not = 0$ and $r_n \to r$ there must exist some $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$ we have that $r_n \not = 0$. This then allows us to perform the division by $r_n$ (for $n$ sufficiently large).

Comment: I see where you are getting at. But we already know $r_n$ is non-zero since they are the absolute value of $z_n$, a sequence in G which does not contain origin. Thus, $r_n$ is non-zero for all $n$.

Comment: In this problem as stated, sure :)

Comment: Finally, how do you conclude $\theta_n \to \theta$ from $\sin \theta_n \to \sin \theta$ ?

Comment: Right, so once we have $\cos \theta_n \to \cos \theta$, we just compose with the continuous inverse function $\cos^{-1}$ to obtain $\cos^{-1} \cos \theta_n \to \cos^{-1} \cos \theta$. The problem now just that we do not know the sign of e.g. $\cos^{-1} \cos \theta_n$ (it could be $\theta_n$ or $-\theta_n$. But we can at least conclude $\lvert \theta_n \rvert = \lvert \cos^{-1} \cos \theta_n \rvert \to \lvert \cos^{-1} \cos \theta \rvert = \lvert \theta \rvert$.

Comment: If $\theta = 0$ then we are done, since $\lvert \theta_n \rvert \to 0$ if and only if $\theta_n \to 0$. Otherwise we can assume $\theta \not = 0$, and need to argue that the sign of $\theta_n$ is eventually (for $n$ large enough) always the same as the sign of $\theta$. We do this just using the fact that $\sin \theta_n \to \sin \theta$; we can assume that $\theta_n \not = 0$ as well (by the same argument I gave above for $r_n$), in which case $\operatorname{sign}(\theta_n) = \operatorname{sign}(\sin \theta_n) \to \operatorname{sign}(\sin \theta) = \operatorname{sign}(\theta)$.

Comment: But now we can just multiply this pair of converging sequences and get: $\theta_n = \operatorname{sign}(\theta_n) \lvert \theta_n \rvert \to \operatorname{sign}(\theta) \lvert \theta \rvert  = \theta$. (Here $\operatorname{sign}$ is the so-called "sign-function".)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131007/discussion-between-approximation-and-keeley-hoek).